# Installing PDFtotext in R

Tags: r, pdf, pdftotext

I am trying to run the `PDFtotext` package in R.

**When I run these commands**:

```
library(tm) pdf=readPDF(control=list(text="-layout"))(elem=list(uri=uri), language="en", id="idi")
```

**I get this error**:

> Error in system2("pdftotext", c(control$text, shQuote(x), "-"), stdout = TRUE) : "pdftotext" not found
>
> In addition: Warning message: running command "pdfinfo" "C:*****\NCLR AR 2005.pdf" had status 127

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: `Sys.which("pdftotext")` is `""`? I.e. the file is not found. Have you installed it? You may want to try the package `pdftools` as an alternative to read pdfs.

Comment: This function of the `tm` library requires that `pdftotext` and `pdfinfo` are installed on your computer. You can download precombiled binaries for the most common operating systems [here](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html). These programs are **not** installed in or by R, as the title of your question suggests. They need to be installed as separate programs on your system.

Answer (score 0):

In widows add the binary to your path. System-->Advanced -->Environment Variables -->add the directory containing the pdftotext.exe